# 'Enterprise_Index_Model_Action_Exception' with message 'Can't perform operation, incomplete metadata!'

Tags: enterprise-1.13, upgrade

Getting this error after an upgrade and after I try to run

php indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_product.

Please Help to solve this Problem.

Comment: Is there a way I can reset all the meta data and rerun indexes

Comment: Have you followed official upgrade instructions? Running URL migration script etc?

Comment: Yes we did, there was an issue going from 1.12 to 1.13.1 with some 1.6 files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento provided a patch for this error

app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/sql/catalog_setup/upgrade-1.6.0.0.18.1.1-1.6.0.0.18.1.2.php

Sorry, this is silly but I couldn't see where to simply attach a file to this?

```
#!/bin/bash
# Patch apllying tool template
# v0.1.2
# (c) Copyright 2013. Magento Inc.
#
# DO NOT CHANGE ANY LINE IN THIS FILE.

# 1. Check required system tools
_check_installed_tools() {
    local missed=""

    until [ -z "$1" ]; do
        type -t $1 >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
        if (( $? != 0 )); then
            missed="$missed $1"
        fi
        shift
    done

    echo $missed
}

REQUIRED_UTILS='sed patch'
MISSED_REQUIRED_TOOLS=`_check_installed_tools $REQUIRED_UTILS`
if (( `echo $MISSED_REQUIRED_TOOLS | wc -w` > 0 ));
then
    echo -e "Error! Some required system tools, that are utilized in this sh script, are not installed:\nTool(s) \"$MISSED_REQUIRED_TOOLS\" is(are) missed, please install it(them)."
    exit 1
fi

# 2. Determine bin path for system tools
CAT_BIN=`which cat`
PATCH_BIN=`which patch`
SED_BIN=`which sed`
PWD_BIN=`which pwd`
BASENAME_BIN=`which basename`

BASE_NAME=`$BASENAME_BIN "$0"`

# 3. Help menu
if [ "$1" = "-?" -o "$1" = "-h" -o "$1" = "--help" ]
then
    $CAT_BIN << EOFH
Usage: sh $BASE_NAME [--help] [-R|--revert] [--list]
Apply embedded patch.

-R, --revert    Revert previously applied embedded patch
--list          Show list of applied patches
--help          Show this help message
EOFH
    exit 0
fi

# 4. Get "revert" flag and "list applied patches" flag
REVERT_FLAG=
SHOW_APPLIED_LIST=0
if [ "$1" = "-R" -o "$1" = "--revert" ]
then
    REVERT_FLAG=-R
fi
if [ "$1" = "--list" ]
then
    SHOW_APPLIED_LIST=1
fi

# 5. File pathes
CURRENT_DIR=`$PWD_BIN`/
APP_ETC_DIR=`echo "$CURRENT_DIR""app/etc/"`
APPLIED_PATCHES_LIST_FILE=`echo "$APP_ETC_DIR""applied.patches.list"`

# 6. Show applied patches list if requested
if [ "$SHOW_APPLIED_LIST" -eq 1 ] ; then
    echo -e "Applied/reverted patches list:"
    if [ -e "$APPLIED_PATCHES_LIST_FILE" ]
    then
        if [ ! -r "$APPLIED_PATCHES_LIST_FILE" ]
        then
            echo "ERROR: \"$APPLIED_PATCHES_LIST_FILE\" must be readable so applied patches list can be shown."
            exit 1
        else
            $SED_BIN -n "/SUP-\|SUPEE-/p" $APPLIED_PATCHES_LIST_FILE
        fi
    else
        echo "<empty>"
    fi
    exit 0
fi

# 7. Check applied patches track file and its directory
_check_files() {
    if [ ! -e "$APP_ETC_DIR" ]
    then
        echo "ERROR: \"$APP_ETC_DIR\" must exist for proper tool work."
        exit 1
    fi

    if [ ! -w "$APP_ETC_DIR" ]
    then
        echo "ERROR: \"$APP_ETC_DIR\" must be writeable for proper tool work."
        exit 1
    fi

    if [ -e "$APPLIED_PATCHES_LIST_FILE" ]
    then
        if [ ! -w "$APPLIED_PATCHES_LIST_FILE" ]
        then
            echo "ERROR: \"$APPLIED_PATCHES_LIST_FILE\" must be writeable for proper tool work."
            exit 1
        fi
    fi
}

_check_files

# 8. Apply/revert patch
# Note: there is no need to check files permissions for files to be patched.
# "patch" tool will not modify any file if there is not enough permissions for all files to be modified.
# Get start points for additional information and patch data
SKIP_LINES=$((`$SED_BIN -n "/^__PATCHFILE_FOLLOWS__$/=" "$CURRENT_DIR""$BASE_NAME"` + 1))
ADDITIONAL_INFO_LINE=$(($SKIP_LINES - 3))p

_apply_revert_patch() {
    DRY_RUN_FLAG=
    if [ "$1" = "dry-run" ]
    then
        DRY_RUN_FLAG=" --dry-run"
        echo "Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully..."
    fi
    PATCH_APPLY_REVERT_RESULT=`$SED_BIN -e '1,/^__PATCHFILE_FOLLOWS__$/d' "$CURRENT_DIR""$BASE_NAME" | $PATCH_BIN $DRY_RUN_FLAG $REVERT_FLAG -p0`
    PATCH_APPLY_REVERT_STATUS=$?
    if [ $PATCH_APPLY_REVERT_STATUS -eq 1 ] ; then
        echo -e "ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.\n\n$PATCH_APPLY_REVERT_RESULT"
        exit 1
    fi
    if [ $PATCH_APPLY_REVERT_STATUS -eq 2 ] ; then
        echo -e "ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully."
        exit 2
    fi
}

REVERTED_PATCH_MARK=
if [ -n "$REVERT_FLAG" ]
then
    REVERTED_PATCH_MARK=" | REVERTED"
fi

_apply_revert_patch dry-run
_apply_revert_patch

# 9. Track patch applying result
echo "Patch was applied/reverted successfully."
ADDITIONAL_INFO=`$SED_BIN -n ""$ADDITIONAL_INFO_LINE"" "$CURRENT_DIR""$BASE_NAME"`
APPLIED_REVERTED_ON_DATE=`date -u +"%F %T UTC"`
APPLIED_REVERTED_PATCH_INFO=`echo -n "$APPLIED_REVERTED_ON_DATE"" | ""$ADDITIONAL_INFO""$REVERTED_PATCH_MARK"`
echo -e "$APPLIED_REVERTED_PATCH_INFO\n$PATCH_APPLY_REVERT_RESULT\n\n" >> "$APPLIED_PATCHES_LIST_FILE"

exit 0


SUPEE-2048 | EE_1.13.0.2 | v1 | a261d4f927772b44922d8e80652cc19ff70c341e | Tue Sep 17 10:06:05 2013 -0700 | 8821856958b5d9c832b7b8106f09cc90012ae701

__PATCHFILE_FOLLOWS__
diff --git app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml
index db1227c..9abcf15 100644
--- app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml
+++ app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml
@@ -28,7 +28,7 @@
 <config>
     <modules>
         <Mage_Catalog>
-            <version>1.6.0.0.18</version>
+            <version>1.6.0.0.18.1.2</version>
         </Mage_Catalog>
     </modules>
     <admin>
diff --git app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/sql/catalog_setup/upgrade-1.6.0.0.18.1.1-1.6.0.0.18.1.2.php app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/sql/catalog_setup/upgrade-1.6.0.0.18.1.1-1.6.0.0.18.1.2.php
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..f284ea1
--- /dev/null
+++ app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/sql/catalog_setup/upgrade-1.6.0.0.18.1.1-1.6.0.0.18.1.2.php
@@ -0,0 +1,66 @@
+<?php
+/**
+ * Magento Enterprise Edition
+ *
+ * NOTICE OF LICENSE
+ *
+ * This source file is subject to the Magento Enterprise Edition License
+ * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_EE.txt.
+ * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
+ * http://www.magentocommerce.com/license/enterprise-edition
+ * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
+ * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
+ * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
+ *
+ * DISCLAIMER
+ *
+ * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
+ * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
+ * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
+ *
+ * @category    Mage
+ * @package     Mage_Catalog
+ * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2013 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
+ * @license     http://www.magentocommerce.com/license/enterprise-edition
+ */
+
+/** @var $installer Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup */
+$installer  = $this;
+/**
+ * Create table 'catalog/category_product_indexer_tmp'
+ */
+if (!$installer->tableExists('catalog/category_product_indexer_tmp')) {
+    $table = $installer->getConnection()
+        ->newTable($installer->getTable('catalog/category_product_indexer_tmp'))
+        ->addColumn('category_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
+            'unsigned'  => true,
+            'nullable'  => false,
+            'default'   => '0',
+        ), 'Category ID')
+        ->addColumn('product_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
+            'unsigned'  => true,
+            'nullable'  => false,
+            'default'   => '0',
+        ), 'Product ID')
+        ->addColumn('position', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
+            'nullable'  => false,
+            'default'   => '0',
+        ), 'Position')
+        ->addColumn('is_parent', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
+            'unsigned'  => true,
+            'nullable'  => false,
+            'default'   => '0',
+        ), 'Is Parent')
+        ->addColumn('store_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
+            'unsigned'  => true,
+            'nullable'  => false,
+            'default'   => '0',
+        ), 'Store ID')
+        ->addColumn('visibility', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
+            'unsigned'  => true,
+            'nullable'  => false,
+        ), 'Visibility')
+        ->setComment('Catalog Category Product Indexer Temp Table')
+        ->setOption('type', Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql::ENGINE_MEMORY);
+    $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
+}
```

Comment: Nice can you share what the patch consisted of? Also if that fixed the error feel free to mark the answer as accepted.